# Unable to upload a file to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to be able to upload a file inside my hard disk to Google Drive using program as follows:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
this_file = 'apple.txt'
this_file.Upload()
```

However, I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Upload'
```

How can I upload it?

Comment: this_file is a string. Not sure how you use this api though, what example are you copying?

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#creating-and-updating-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html) says to do this:

```
this_file = drive.CreateFile()
this_file.SetContentFile('apple.txt') # Read file and set it as a content of this instance.
this_file.Upload() # Upload it
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload a string. 
You should create a file stream and then call the upload method on it.

```
this_file = open("apple.txt","r")
this_file.Upload()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I got the following error AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'Upload'